# Swift 4: Value of type '(SomeUIViewController) -> () -> (SomeUIViewController)' has no member 'someMemberItem'

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am programmatically trying to open a new UIViewController from a different UITableViewCell selection programmatically.

I am doing this like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destination = SomeUIViewController()
    destination.someMemberItem = someDataArray[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}
```

`SomeUIViewController` is a `UIViewController` that has one variable member that I need it to display.

`SomeUIViewController` is initialized like so:

```
class SomeUIViewController: UIViewController {
    var someMemberItem : SomeMemberItemStruct

    // MARK: Layout
    let someMemberItemImage: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 300, height: 300))
        if let imageUrl = self.someMemberItem.imageUrl {
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)
            view.image? = UIImage(data: data)
        } else {
            view.image = nil // Set default image
        }
        return view
    }()

    let someMemberItemLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 50))
        label.text = self.someMemberItem.name
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()

    func setUpNavigationBar() {
        navigationItem.title = self.someMemberItem.name
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(r: 30, g: 255, b: 198)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
    }

    func setUpSomeMemberItemView() {
        self.view.addSubview(someMemberItemLabel)
        self.view.addSubview(someMemberItemImage)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNavigationBar()
        setUpSomeMemberItemView()
    }
}

public extension UIColor {
    public convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

As stated above, this entire application is done programmatically.

I'm getting an error that says "Class 'SomeUIViewController' has no initializers"

I get the same error on these lines here:

```
if let imageUrl = self.someMemberItem.imageUrl {
```

and

```
label.text = self.someMemberItem.name
```

Where the error says "Value of type '(SomeUIViewController) -> () -> (SomeUIViewController)' has no member 'someMemberItem'".

Has anyone experienced this error before and know how to resolve it?

Update:

`SomeMemberItemStruct` is defined as such:

```
public struct SomeMemberItemStruct: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name : String
    let imageUrl : String?
    let description : String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case imageUrl
        case description
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide information of your "SomeMemberItemClass" class

Comment: @Khushbu SomeMemberItem is a struct, not a class, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because of

```
var someMemberItem : SomeMemberItemClass
```

As per [Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) You    `SomeUIViewController` has no initialiser that define default value of  `someMemberItem`

if it was struct then there will no any error because struct by default provides **Memberwise Initializers** unlike class

> if your custom type has a stored property that is logically allowed to have “no value”—perhaps because its value cannot be set during initialization, or because it is allowed to have “no value” at some later point—declare the property with an optional type. Properties of optional type are automatically initialized with a value of nil, indicating that the property is deliberately intended to have “no value yet” during initialization.

you have following options

1) Provide Default Value

2) Make it optional

Comment: `SomeMemberItem` is a struct, I had mistyped. I am getting the error with a struct.

Comment: @Q.H. But you can't declare property without it initial value or optional or lazy type. inside class

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `lazy` initialization of the subviews solved the problems I was having. That is, saying

```
lazy var someMemberItemLabel: UILabel = {
    // 
}()
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: don't you mean "and such and so forth"?  ;-)